# Laravel database structure suggestion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need a suggestion for structuring the database.

Basically, I have this `Project` model, and each project will have a thumbnail image, the main image and a featured image, meaning that if it gets featured on the site, it will show that special feature image. So at the moment, my model has 3 different properties: `thumbnail_image` `featured_image` `primary_image`.

When uploading each image, the name is automatically generated using a random string. Each project has its own folder and therefore the `Project` model also has `images_folder` property.

It all works fine, I'm just a bit concerned that it is not scalable having these 3 image names being saved in the same table where project details are. So I was thinking to perhaps create `images` table with a `type` property. But I have a feeling that this will clutter the relationships a lot down the line.

Any other suggestions perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the images in their own table will lead to more overhead, since you would have to query the relationship every time for even one of those images. Having it in the project table is perfectly fine and you shouldn't be bothered. In case you want to make things simpler, you could try this approach.

Generated image name - somerandomname.jpg

```
primary_image   : somerandomname.jpg
featured_image  : somerandomname_featured.jpg
thumbnail_image : somerandomname_thumb.jpg
```

Store the image name under a common field say `image`. There the field `image` would contain the value `somerandomname.jpg`.

Then add the following to your Model.

```
protected $appends = [
    'primary_image', 'featured_image', 'thumbnail_image'
];

public function getPrimaryImageAttribute()
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function getFeaturedImageAttribute()
{
    return str_replace('.jpg', '_featured.jpg', $this->image);
}

public function getThumbnailImageAttribute()
{
    return str_replace('.jpg', '_thumb.jpg', $this->image);
}
```

These accessors would let you fetch the image like any database field. The `appends` property automatically adds all those fields to every model result.